# Debugging ASP.NET app results in "Unable to start program 'http://localhost:xxx'. The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8. When I try to interactively debug any web project using IE10 this error message is shown:

> Unable to start program '`http://localhost:9999`'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The app is configured to run under IIS Express. The same error message is shown when trying to use Visual Studio Development Server.

When debugging with Chrome and Firefox everything is fine. The problem only presents when using IE.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Is IIS (or IIS Express) running? Can't view the site otherwise.

Comment: It's IIS Express. I can view the site, but I need to 'Browse With' any browser than IE.

Comment: Nominating for re-open. I have this exact same problem in the same development environment configuration.

Comment: Lots of developers have [reported this to Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/a469a1a4-5890-4fe2-92f5-256a1aad845a/) for Windows 8 + VS 2012